# Can't solve this series...

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to solve for the closed form of the following series:

$$
S_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n} {n^2-k^2}x^n
$$

I can't seem to get it in terms of any known series.  Differentiating, Integrating, forming a DE, nothing really pinpoints a worthy direction.  I must be missing something here.

Comment: I get $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x \left[\left(\frac{x}{\tau}\right)^k+\left(\frac{\tau}{x}\right)^k\right] \frac{d\tau}{1-\tau}$, but I'm not sure this is possible to express with elementary functions. Wolfram Alpha yields a hypergeometric function when persuaded. Then again, plugging the original series into W|A results in invocation of Lerch transcendent, a more specific form of special function that doesn't require as much work to obtain.

Comment: I saw that.  Too bad I'm incredibly lousy at special functions. HG, Legendre, and Bessel functions always hurt when they hit me.

Comment: $k$ is something other than an integer, to avoid a term with denominator zero.

Answer (score 1):

Maple says
$$
\frac{\Phi \left( x,1,k \right) +\Phi \left( x
,1,-k \right)}{2}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.

Comment: This makes sense when you write $$\frac{n}{n^2-k^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{n-k}+\frac1{n+k}\right)$$